# How to write linux bash alias to keep waiting for a file until it appears and tail once it appears

Tags: linux, bash, alias, shortcut

I want to create a linux bash alias which does:
1. In case the file mentioned doesn't exist, then wait for it to exist
2. In case the file exists, then output the file contents

Currently, this is what I have done:

```
alias applog = 'while [! -e /usr/share/tomcat8/logs/application.log ] do sleep 2 done; tail -f /usr/share/tomcat8/logs/application.log'
```

But I get the below:

```
[ec2-user@ip-17-29-17-29 ~]$ applog
>
```

Comment: You're missing a semicolon between `sleep 2` and `done`. So, `"done"` is passed as a second argument to `sleep` (which ignores it) and your `do` loop is unterminated

Comment: thanks! I added the semicolon between sleep 2 and done.

alias applog='while [! -e /usr/share/tomcat8/logs/application.log ] do sleep 2; done ; tail -f /usr/share/tomcat8/logs/application.log'.

But I get the below error:
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `done'

Comment: Do you get that when you just write the command directly instead of as an alias?

Comment: there is also a space missing after `[`,  and semicolon missing before do and before done, and no space must be around =

Comment: Good question.. it is working if I use directly

Answer (score 0):

```
alias applog='while ! tail -f /usr/share/tomcat8/logs/application.log ; do sleep 2 ; done'
```

Comment: @ndmeiri thanks for the help! it is working as expected :)

Comment: It was me who answered, @ndmeiri thanks for the edit
You can mark it as the answer.

Comment: lol.. sorry, my bad. I am a newbie in asking questions on SO. Cheers @in need of help